# How to log or capture information and errors when calling AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm looking for a way that I can capture information about an Ajax call. I've been asked to look into a small web site that is using KnockOut and jQuery/Ajax because some end users have been having issues with the site just sitting there with the processing .gif running.

So, looking at the code the developer is using jQuery to make an Ajax call to an API. What I don't know how to do is capture or log what the user is searching on as well as any errors.

The end user just replies to us saying the site is just sitting there spinning and nothing happens. They'll usually send a screen shot off their cell phone and at least that way I can see what they entered.

If there is an error is there a way I can stop the Ajax call and display the user an error as well as hopefully capture some detailed error information I can go look up?

Here it the JS code for the submit button

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    self.validateDate();
    self.validateOrigin();
    self.srchMessage("No records found.")

    var origin = $("#txtOrigin").val();
    var destination = $("#txtDestination").val();
    var flightDate = $("#txtDate").val();
    var flightNo = $("#txtFlightNo").val();

    if (flightNo == '') {
        flightNo = 'ALL';
    }
    if (destination == '') {
        destination = "ALL";
    }
    if (origin == '') {
        origin = "ALL";
    }

    if (!self.orginRequired() && !self.dateRequired()) {
        var serviceUrl = webApihostName + 'apiflight/v2/flight/' + origin + '/' + destination + '/' + flightNo + '/' + flightDate;

        self.progressIcon(true);
        self.tblVisible(false);
        self.noRecordsMsg(false);
        self.flightViewModel.removeAll();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: serviceUrl,
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'BindData',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            error: function (e) {
                // console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

The way I read the code is that it first sets some validation JS and sets the default search message to "No records found".

Then it looks at the textboxes and either gets values or sets the values to "All".

Then it creates a API URI with that information called serviceUrl.

Then it turns on the progress .gif to let the user know something is going on, hides the table to display the search results, and I guess removes the flight view model.

Then it makes the call to the API.

However, if there is an error, nothing is being done. Obviously is a problem if there actually is an error.

I did some research and tried the following in the error section but the next day after I added the code the user called back again with the same issue.

```
error: function (e, xhr) {
    self.progressIcon(false);
    self.srchMessage("Error retrieving data. " + xhr.responseText);
    self.noRecordsMsg(true);

    // console.log(e.message);
}
```

Anyone have some examples on how I can get or display error information. I would love to use NLog to capture it but I'm pretty sure that won't be possible since this won't be server side. I'm also not exactly sure how I can force an error to be able to test something locally on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here some tricks to get request errors.

```
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    /**** REPLACE CURRENT DOCUMENT WITH SERVER RESPONSE**/
    document.open();
    document.write(xhr.responseText);
    document.close();

    /**** LOGS JSON RESPONSE IF ANY ***/
    console.log(xhr.responseJSON);

    /**** LOGS JQUERY REQUEST STATUS. POSSIBLE VALUES: "timeout", "error", "abort", "parsererror" ***/
    console.log(textStatus);

    /**** LOGS HTTP ERROR IF ANY ***/
    console.log(errorThrown);

}
```

Comment: So the first one will display a pop-up type window with the response text but the others with log to the console log which can only be seen with the developer tools (F12)?

Comment: The first replaces the current page with the page sent by the server (if any). The others are visible only with f12 yes